# Test httpclient requests without running on device or emulator

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am building an app in nativescript and making a number of web api calls using the HttpClient from Angular with NativeScriptHttpClientModule.

Is there a simple way of testing, say in NodeJs the same code by creating a HttpClient, but without using nativescripts module?

This way I can quickly run code in nodejs to test functionality which pushes/pulls data from my rest api without having to load to emulator/device each time, as the functionality im testing isnt device related, but more the with transformation of the data from API.

I import HttpClient from angular:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse, } from "@angular/common/http";
```

Is there any easy way to instantiate HttpClient that I can use in nodejs?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Why not postman ?

Comment: im happy with the url endpoints. I just want to test the javascript code which will consume the api and pass on to other code within my app. its just becoming time consuming any time I want to change something in the say the mapping process in javascript

Comment: So you want to test Ajax calls because you fear they will not work ? I don't see your need here.

Comment: i dont fear they wont work. I know they work. That isnt my ask here. I want to run code to get data from an api. Do something with the data, say transform to a javascript object, apply logic, run checks etc. due to the different results from the web service, i need to code for different scenarios etc. This becomes time consuming when having to run on a device/emulator each time.

Comment: If you just want to test your logic, then you should probably use Unit Testing tools like Jasmine and test your utility functions.

Comment: Well then yeah, you can use [request](https://github.com/request/request) for node scripts, but then again, if it's not automated, postman would do the job pretty well.

Comment: I am using axios at the moment in nodejs. But then the code im generating in the data service is not the same that will be run in live. So my dataservice uses HttpClient to do posts then this is piped using rxjs for example. So i want to sub out the httpclient but test all the other functionality that isnt device specific.

Comment: As already mentioned, you should setup a unit testing framework for that - like jest or karma/jasmine.